# Underestimated Coverage probability

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, sampling, random-effects-model, coverage-probability

Let $U0$ denotes intercept variance and $U1$ denotes slope variance.

Given that the coverage rate for the intercept variance is $91$% $(U0)$ , and the coverage rate for the slope variance is $91.2$% $(U1)$ . Also nominal coverage rate is $95$%.

Then it is written that

> The amount of coverage here implies that the standard errors for the  variance components are estimated about  $15$% too small.

I have not understood from the information of "coverage rate for the intercept variance $91$% $(U0)$ and  coverage rate for the slope variance $91.2$% $(U1)$", how is the calculation  "the standard errors for the  variance components are estimated about $15$% too small"  derived ?

For double check , you can consider the following :

The coverage rate for slope variance is $91.2$%. This amount implies that the standard errors for the  slope variance is estimated about $3.1$% too small when the nominal coverage rate is $95$%.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be correct to infer that these are *two-sided* confidence intervals? We are limited in what we can guess until you tell us more about what "variance components" means (it has a conventional meaning that does not appear to apply here) and how the confidence intervals for these variance components are computed.  What are the formulas?

Comment: @whuber I have two-level regression model and the variance components  are second level variances. And the author used confidence interval based on asymptotic normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nominal coverave probability is $95\%$, so your interval is estimated as $[\mu-1.96\hat{\sigma};[\mu-1.96\hat{\sigma}]$ because you find a $95\%$ value (in R) as 'qnorm(p=0.975) = qnorm(p=1.95/2)'. This value is 1.96 and is derived from tha standard normal distribution (note is $z$)

In one or another way (probably by simulation) the authros find that the true coverage probability is $91\%$.  So with this you have (qnorm(p=1.91/2)=1.695) , for this same sigma an true $91\%$ interval of $[\mu-1.695\hat{\sigma}_{real};\mu+1.695\hat{\sigma}_{real}]$, so $1.695\hat{\sigma}_{real}=1.96\hat{\sigma}]$ of $\hat{\sigma}=\frac{1.695}{1.96}\hat{\sigma_{real}}$, or an underestimation of $\frac{1.695}{1.96}-1=-13.5\%$, so more or less $15\%$ underestimated.

**Answers to the questions in the comments:**

First, why subtract 1 ? If you want to have the relative difference between two numbers $a$ and $b$, so how much percent (of a) is the difference between a and b, then you compute $\frac{b-a}{a}=\frac{b}{a}-1$, e.g. the how much is 95 different from 100 in pct? $\frac{95}{100}-1=0.95-1=-0.05$.

The relation between the two sigma's ? The nomilal coverage probability of $[\mu-1.96\hat{\sigma};\mu+1.96\hat{\sigma}]$ is $95\%$, but the authors know that this same interval has a true coverage probability of $92\%$, so it is **the same interval** as $[\mu-1.695\hat{\sigma}_{real};\mu+1.695\hat{\sigma}_{real}]$, but if these two intervals are the same, then it must hold that $1.695\hat{\sigma}_{real}=1.96\hat{\sigma}]$

Comment: But  I can't calculate `The coverage rate for slope variance is 91.2%. This amount implies that the standard errors for the slope variance is estimated about 3.1% too small when the nominal coverage rate is 95%` in a similar manner that you have described.

Comment: Could you please explain how we can equate $1.695\hat\sigma_{real}$ to $1.96\hat\sigma$, that is , $1.695\hat\sigma_{real}=1.96\hat\sigma$ ? I think there is a theorem behind it. Could you give me reference? And Why have you subtracted $1$ from $\frac{1.695}{1.96}$, that is, $\frac{1.695}{1.96}-1$ ?

Comment: I added a section to my answers where I try to explain this, so please take a look at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: If the true coverage probability is derived from *profile confidence interval*, will I still find the z-value ? or the reference and tabulated value will be calculated from $\chi^2$ ?